# ReactJs/Redux Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(LoginContainer)"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, jestjs

Not sure why I'm getting this error, it happened when I added `connect` from `redux` to my Login component, so I could connect my `store`.

> FAIL  src/components/auth/Login.test.js
>
> ● Test suite failed to run
>
> Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(LoginContainer)". Either wrap the root component in a `<Provider>`, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(LoginContainer)".

[image]

#### Index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from "react-redux"
import { createCommonStore } from "./store";
import App from './App'
import css from './manage2.scss'

const store = createCommonStore();
const element = document.getElementById('manage2');
console.log("Index.js Default store", store.getState());

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>  // <-- store added here
        <App />
    </Provider>, element);
```

#### store.js

```
import React from "react"
import { applyMiddleware, combineReducers, compose, createStore} from "redux"
import thunk from "redux-thunk"
import { userReducer } from "./reducers/UserReducer"
import { authReducer } from "./reducers/AuthReducer"

export const createCommonStore = (trackStore=false) => {
    const reducers = combineReducers({
        user: userReducer,
        user: authReducer
    });

    //noinspection JSUnresolvedVariable
    const store = createStore(reducers,
        compose(
            applyMiddleware(thunk),
            window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
        )
    );

    if (trackStore) {
        store.subscribe((() => {
            console.log("  store changed", store.getState());
        }));
    }

    return store;
};
```

#### App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import Routes from './components/Routes'
const supportsHistory = "pushState" in window.history

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router forceRefresh={!supportsHistory}>
                <Routes />
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

#### Routes.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import LoginContainer from './auth/Login'
import Dashboard from './Dashboard'
import NoMatch from './NoMatch'

const Routes = () => {
    return (
        <Switch>
            <Route exact={ true } path="/" component={ LoginContainer }/>
            <Route path="/dashboard" component={ Dashboard }/>
            <Route component={ NoMatch } />
        </Switch>
    );
}

export default Routes
```

#### Finally Login.js (code removed for brevity

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'; 
import { setCurrentUser } from '../../actions/authActions'
import * as api from '../../services/api'

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    console.log('mapDispatchToProps', dispatch);
    return {
        setUser: (user) => {
            bindActionCreators(setCurrentUser(user), dispatch)
        }
    }
}

class LoginContainer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {};

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(e) {
    }

    handleSubmit(e) {
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="app-bg">
                ...
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginContainer);
```

#### Login.test

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactTestUtils from 'react-dom/test-utils'
import { mount, shallow } from 'enzyme'
import toJson from 'enzyme-to-json'
import { missingLogin } from '../../consts/errors'
import Login from './Login'
import Notification from '../common/Notification'

const loginComponent = shallow(<Login />);
const fakeEvent = { preventDefault: () => '' };

describe('<Login /> component', () => {
    it('should render', () => {
        const tree = toJson(loginComponent);
        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
    });

    it('should render the Notification component if state.error is true', () => {
        loginComponent.setState({ error: true });
        expect(loginComponent.find(Notification).length).toBe(1);
    });
});

describe('User Login', () => {
    it('should fail if no credentials are provided', () => {
        expect(loginComponent.find('.form-login').length).toBe(1);
        loginComponent.find('.form-login').simulate('submit', fakeEvent);
        expect(loginComponent.find(Notification).length).toBe(1);
        const notificationComponent = shallow(<Notification message={ missingLogin }/>);
        expect(notificationComponent.text()).toEqual('Please fill out both username and password.');
    });

    it('input fields should be filled correctly', () => {
        const credentials = { username: 'leongaban', password: 'testpass' };
        expect(loginComponent.find('#input-auth-username').length).toBe(1);

        const usernameInput = loginComponent.find('#input-auth-username');
        usernameInput.value = credentials.username;
        expect(usernameInput.value).toBe('leongaban');

        const passwordInput = loginComponent.find('#input-auth-password');
        passwordInput.value = credentials.password;
        expect(passwordInput.value).toBe('testpass');
    });
});
```

What do you see wrong here?

Comment: where is createCommonStore  code,

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri just added it sorry! store.js

Comment: in your index.js do a console.log() to see if you get the store defiend

Comment: can you provide login.test.js file?

Comment: @lavish added the test

Comment: How do you connect the store in the test?

Comment: Oh I am not doing that, what would be the correct way to include the store in the test?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Redux recommends exporting the unconnected component for unit tests.  See their [docs](https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests#connected-components).

In login.js:

```
// Named export for tests
export class LoginContainer extends React.Component {
}

// Default export
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginContainer);
```

And in your test:

```
// Import the named export, which has not gone through the connect function
import { LoginContainer as Login } from './Login';
```

You can then specify any props that would have come from the store directly on the component.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm using to import the Login component into my test, however I'm currently not using the store in my Login code as you see above. Could that be where the problem is?

Comment: @LeonGaban That's not what you're doing in the code in the question.  You're importing the connected component as a default export.  This is importing the unconnected component as a named export.

Comment: Ok, did that, still getting errors. What else do I need in the test? https://gist.github.com/leongaban/770713a4d7f542c725c46cf5db47cae2

Comment: Ah! That was it! Sorry I was seeing an error in my Routes test. So the Provider worked inside of the test! Now getting a cannot read property 'apply' of undefined now, but that is a new error. 18 hrs before I can check your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass store as either a prop or context in your test. mount method accepts context as another parameter.

and how do you get store here? You create store the same way you created in app.js

Comment: Could you post an example of how to do this in a jest test? Currently I'm using the Provider component in my index.js to insert the store into my app. Really unsure as to how to accomplish this in my tests. My index.js is at the top of my question.

Answer (score -1):

You could use React's contextType or pass propType. You would need to declare it either as a prop or contextType.

```
Provider.contextTypes = {
  Store: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

 Provider.propTypes= {
  Store: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
```

Comment: And which module would this go in? Or is this in the test?