# Invariant Violation: Could Not find "store" in either context of props of "Connect(App)"

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

Note, before reading I have already looked at the following:

[JestJS -> Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(Portfolio)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44813111/jestjs-invariant-violation-could-not-find-store-in-either-the-context-or-p)

[ReactJs/Redux Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(LoginContainer)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44458605/reactjs-redux-invariant-violation-could-not-find-store-in-either-the-context)

[Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(App)" In an react-redux app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49535544/could-not-find-store-in-either-the-context-or-props-of-connectapp-in-an-re)

Also, I followed the tutorial shown here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9mlwjZL3Fmw

The major difference is that I used `create-react-native-app` to initialize my project where the video creator does not.

I want to know if it's possible to get the connect to recognize all the components while keeping the App component in `App.js` as a js const. 
The previous solutions offered work when I switch to using a javascript class instead:

`class App extends React.Component {` etc..

The code is available here: https://github.com/qxh5696/first-react-native-app

I'd like to find the root cause as to why the "store" is not being recognized. Call it stubbornness but I am curious to know if anyone has found a solution to this problem.

Comment: maybe try the changes i made here: https://github.com/DeveloperACE/first-react-native-app (ill probably take it down eventually FYI). im pretty sure it wont do much but i was just looking at your code and noticed that you could simplify your `./configureStore.js` by not exporting a function and then more directly using that in your index files instead of creating that intermediary variable.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of the error is when we put together a react-redux application we should expect to see a structure where at the top we have the `Provider` tag which has an instance of a redux store.

That `Provider` tag then renders your parent component, lets call it the `App` component which in turn renders every other component inside the application.

Here is the key part, when we wrap a component with the `connect()` function, that `connect()` function expects to see some parent component within the hierarchy that has the `Provider` tag.

So the instance you put the `connect()` function in there, it will look up the hierarchy and try to find the `Provider`.

Thats what you want to have happen, but in your test environment that flow is breaking down.

Comment: Thanks for bringing up the hierarchy!

Answer (score 0):

import

```
import {connect} from "react-redux";
```

instead of

```
import connect from "react-redux/es/connect/connect";
```